# Entity framework - loading Posts with Tags through a Mapping Table

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework in C# to load data from the following tables:

I have three Tables:

```
Table Post:
PostsID
Name
Description
CreatedBy

Table Tag:
TagID
Title
CreatedBy

Table PostTagMap:
MapID
PostID
TagID
```

I am trying to load the all Posts and I also want load the related tags through the mapping table.

I created the tables in SQL Server and then created EF mapping on it.

Post Class:

```
public Post()
    {
        this.PostsTagsMaps = new HashSet<PostsTagsMaps>();
        this.Tags = new List<Tag>();
    }

public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PostsTagsMap> PostsTagsMaps { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
```

Tag Class:

```
public Tag()
    {

    }

    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PostsTagsMap> PostsTagsMaps { get; set; }


public partial class PostsTagsMap
{

    public int MapId { get; set; }
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public virtual Post Post { get; set; }
    public virtual Tag Tag { get; set; }
}

 posts = context.Posts.Include(c => c.PostsTagsMaps).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can eagerly fetch them using includes on the post tags. Without seeing any code regarding your mappings, it would be something like:

```
posts.Include(post => post.PostTags.Select(postTag => postTag.Tag));
```

Now that you've added some code:

```
posts = context.Posts.Include(c => c.PostsTagsMaps.Select(pt => pt.Tag)).ToList();
```

If you want to access the tags from there, you can always add a read-only property that gets them from the mapping table items.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have updated the question with more details.

Comment: You should not have a collection of Tags on the Post class in that schema. If you can access them through the PostTagsMaps collection. Select the tag in your include.

Comment: Thanks, I am able to get the Tags in the PostTagsMaps, However Now I see circular reference like this:

Post
-PostsTagsMaps
--Tag
---PostsTagsMsps
----Post

Comment: I only need the information deep upto the Post & related tags, it is however giving me Post, related tags then maps for each tag and in each tag related posts. its coming as a very very big object. I don't know what I am not doing right.

Comment: It would be a good idea to remove the virtual from all these. Lazy loading is problematic in EF (especially once you get async involved) ... but it will make this a lot more straight forward, too.

Comment: Thanks I added .AsNoTracking() to the include and it worked.